# Выборка по одному из очереди условий

Tags: sql, база-данных

Подскажите приём для выборки данных удовлетворяющих одному из нескольких условий в соответствии с их приоритетом.

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c INTEGER, z INTEGER, mydata DOUBLE);
```

,где поля A и Z не могут быть `null`, С и Z -- могут.

На выборку передаётся четыре параметра, по одному для каждого поля, кроме `mydata`

- `param_a`
- `param_b`
- `param_c`
- `param_z`

В лучшем случае, надо вернуть результат выборки по четырем полям

```
SELECT mydata 
FROM mytable 
WHERE a = param_a
AND b = param_b
AND c = param_c
AND z = param_z
```

Если ничего не нашли

```
SELECT mydata 
FROM mytable 
WHERE a = param_a
AND b = param_b
AND c IS NULL
AND z = param_z
```

Опять ничего не нашли

```
SELECT mydata 
FROM mytable 
WHERE a = param_a
AND b IS NULL
AND c = param_c
AND z = param_z
```

Последняя попытка

```
SELECT mydata 
FROM mytable 
WHERE a = param_a
AND b IS NULL
AND c IS NULL
AND z = param_z
```

Т.е. нужно, чтобы выбирались строки по одному такому условию, которое возвращает одну или более строк, и имеет наивысший приоритет.

Как представить эту логику одним запросом? Если нельзя одним, то как лучше?

Comment: Какой именно у вас SQL ? попробую придумать что нибудь оптимальное за один проход таблицы без union ...

Comment: @Mike, хотелось бы **стандарт**ное решение. Принимаю ответы для любого диалекта.

Comment: Ну внутреннюю часть стандартно сделать не проблема. а вот наружную - которая отберет именно максимальный приоритет - тут только нестандартные решения или дублирование запроса еще раз да вдобавок с выкрутасами. Потому как предложенный вам сейчас `HAVING prio=max(prio)` нерабочий, ибо колонка без групповой функции не может упоминаться в нем.

Comment: @Mike, напишите на каком вам кажется красивее\интереснее (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Общий вид запроса для любых СУБД практически одинаков. Выбираем записи по условиям, подсчитываем приоритет, отбираем те у которых приоритет максимален. Но получение максимального приоритета одновременно со всеми строками данных на разных СУБД решается по разному. Если есть оконные функции (Postgresql, MS SQL Server, Oracle, SQLite) - то так:

```
select *
  from (
  select m.*,
         case when b is null then 0 else 1 end +
         case when c is null then 0 else 2 end as prio,
         max(case when b is null then 0 else 1 end +
             case when c is null then 0 else 2 end) over() as mprio
    from mytable m
   where a=1 and z=4
     and (b=2 or b is null)
     and (c=3 or c is null)
  ) A
 where prio=mprio
```

Для MySQL, не поддерживающего оконные функции можно использовать переменные:

```
   select A.*
     from (
       select m.*,
              case when b is null then 0 else 1 end +
              case when c is null then 0 else 2 end as prio,
              @mprio:=greatest(@mprio,
                  case when b is null then 0 else 1 end +
                  case when c is null then 0 else 2 end) mprio
         from mytable m,(select @mprio:=0) B
        where a=1 and z=4
          and (b=2 or b is null)
          and (c=3 or c is null)
     ) A
 where prio=mprio
```

На совсем "Стандартном" SQL можно предложить только основу этого запроса и where `prio=select max(case .... ) from mytable ...` т.е. в подзапросе еще раз повторить весь основной запрос. Либо отфильтровать записи на клиенте.

P.S. Перед публикацией запрос был проверен на всех перечисленных СУБД кроме SQLite.

**UPD** Вариант с CTE вместо оконных функций:

```
with Q as(
  select m.*,
         case when b is null then 0 else 1 end +
         case when c is null then 0 else 2 end as prio
    from mytable m
   where a=1 and z=4
     and (b=2 or b is null)
     and (c=3 or c is null)
  )
select * from Q where prio=(select max(prio) from Q)
```

**UPD2** Для СУБД поддерживающих оконную функцию `rank()` запрос можно еще укоротить:

```
select *
  from (
  select m.*,
         rank() over(order by b, c) as R
    from mytable m
   where a=1 and z=4 and coalesce(b,2)=2 and coalesce(c,3)=3
 ) A
 where R=1
```

Comment: *"СУБД с CTE но без оконных функций я еще не видел"* - SQLite, как оказалось. Сработал только вариант с CTE. Вы доработали мой ответ в варианте UPD2 - свой удаляю.

Comment: Приведу результаты стоимости тестовых планов Oracle на 1млн записей. Неиндексированная CTE=8829; Rank=8826; 1й Вар=8825. Индексированная (a,b,c,z) CTE=6; Rank=16; 1й Вар=2

Answer (score 1):

Если с учетом приоритета, то так

```
SELECT
  mydata
FROM (
  SELECT
    0 AS `order`
    mydata 
  FROM
    mytable 
  WHERE
    a = param_a
    AND b = param_b
    AND c = param_c
    AND z = param_z
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1 AS `order`
    mydata 
  FROM
    mytable 
  WHERE
    a = param_a
    AND b = param_b
    AND c IS NULL
    AND z = param_z
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2 AS `order`
    mydata 
  FROM
    mytable 
  WHERE
    a = param_a
    AND b IS NULL
    AND c = param_c
    AND z = param_z
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    3 AS `order`
    mydata 
  FROM
    mytable 
  WHERE
    a = param_a
    AND b IS NULL
    AND c IS NULL
    AND z = param_z
) sub
WHERE
  `order` = (SELECT MIN(`order`) FROM (тот же набор UNION ALL) sub2)
```

Четыре объединенных селекта с последующей фильтрацией.

А лучше это делать через Stored Procedure. Вот процедура на примере Interbase

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_sel(
  in_param_a INTEGER,
  in_param_b INTEGER,
  in_param_c INTEGER,
  in_param_z INTEGER)
RETURNS (
  out_mydata DOUBLE PRECISION)
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE var_exit SMALLINT;
BEGIN
  var_exit = NULL;
  FOR
    SELECT
      mydata,
      1
    FROM
      mytable 
    WHERE
      a = :in_param_a
      AND b = :in_param_b
      AND c = :in_param_c
      AND z = :in_param_z
    INTO
      :out_mydata,
      :var_exit
  DO
    SUSPEND;

  IF (:var_exit IS NOT NULL) THEN
    EXIT;

  FOR
    SELECT
      mydata,
      1
    FROM
      mytable 
    WHERE
      a = :in_param_a
      AND b = :in_param_b
      AND c IS NULL
      AND z = :in_param_z
    INTO
      :out_mydata,
      :var_exit
  DO
    SUSPEND;

  IF (:var_exit IS NOT NULL) THEN
    EXIT;

  FOR
    SELECT
      mydata,
      1
    FROM
      mytable 
    WHERE
      a = :in_param_a
      AND b IS NULL
      AND c = :in_param_c
      AND z = :in_param_z
    INTO
      :out_mydata,
      :var_exit
  DO
    SUSPEND;

  IF (:var_exit IS NOT NULL) THEN
    EXIT;

  FOR
    SELECT
      mydata
    FROM
      mytable 
    WHERE
      a = :in_param_a
      AND b IS NULL
      AND c IS NULL
      AND z = :in_param_z
    INTO
      :out_mydata
  DO
    SUSPEND;
END
```

И вызов

```
SELECT out_mydata FROM sp_sel(param_a, param_b, param_c, param_z)
```

Comment: *"А лучше это делать через Stored Procedure"* - пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ как. Можно кодом %любой_СУБД%, можно псевдокодом, можно словами

Comment: Не лучше ли использовать `UNION ALL` в вашем примере? зачем заставлять СУБД проверять уникальность лишний раз?

Comment: @4per В ответ не решался добавить, т.к. код процедуры будет специфичен для каждой СУБД

Comment: Специфичен синтаксис. Я уверен ваше решение можно будет портировать на большинство СУБД.

Comment: @4per `UNION ALL`, действительно, будет лучше

Comment: `having order=min(order)` гарантированно даст на выходе только одну запись, потому как для вычисления max() ему придется свернуть весь запрос до одной записи. И это будет на MySQL. на всех других СУБД вы получите ошибку о том что используется не сгруппированная колонка

Comment: @Mike Вы правы. Можно, конечно, извратиться еще одним подзапросом...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, интересно, а CTE можно как-то использовать, чтобы не дублировать текст?

Comment: @4per Вы СУБД укажите

Comment: @4per CTE можно, но оконные функции проще, что я и написал в ответе. А СУБД с CTE но без оконных функций я еще не видел

Comment: @4per Добавил CTE вариант в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем уверен что правильно понял, но может так:

```
SELECT mydata 
FROM mytable 
WHERE 
(a = param_a
AND b = param_b
AND c = param_c
AND z = param_z) OR
(a = param_a
AND b = param_b
AND c IS NULL
AND z = param_z) OR
(a = param_a
AND b IS NULL
AND c = param_c
AND z = param_z) OR
(a = param_a
AND b IS NULL
AND c IS NULL
AND z = param_z)
```

Comment: В вашем примере в выборку могут попасть строки таблицы, которые удовлетворяют любому из условий. Мне нужно, чтобы выбирались строки по одному такому условию, которое возвращает одну или более строк, и имеет наивысший приоритет.