# Если в таблице два одинаковых значения в колонке как выбрать только то, у которого установлено значение в другой колонке?

Tags: mysql

```
+------+---------+-------+
|  id  |   name  | prefer|
+------+---------+-------+
|  9   |  Anton  |  null |
+------+---------+-------+
|  10  |   Ilya  |   1   |
+------+---------+-------+
|  10  | Ilyusha |  null |
+------+---------+-------+
|  10  | Elijah  |  null |
+------+---------+-------+
|  11  |   Ivan  |  null |
+------+---------+-------+
|  12  |   Petr  |   1   |
+------+---------+-------+
|  12  |Petruccio| null  |       
+------+---------+-------+
```

выбираем имя по имеющемуся списку ид. если есть одинаковые ид надо брать имя у которого prefer=1. если ид уникален то у него prefer null - то есть простое условие where prefer IS NOT NULL - не прокатит.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588421/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9

Comment: мне бы готовый запрос...

Comment: ``select t2.id, t2.name from (select id, max(prefer) as prefer from `table` group by id) as t1 join `table` as t2 on (t1.id, t1.prefer) <=> (t2.id, t2.prefer)``

Comment: ид должны выбираться из другой таблицы при всём при этом. я не представляю как это реализовать с таким запросом

Comment: наверно надо сначала выбрать все уникальные ид а потом сделать юнион с неуникальными у которых prefer=1....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, ifnull(max(if(prefer=1,name,NULL)), max(name))
  from tabPref
 group by id
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b37aa/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE id = 12
ORDER BY prefer DESC
LIMIT 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0116e7/1/0

Comment: ну это если надо 1 имя выбрать. а я же написал что по списку, т.е. нужны все имена из таблицы.
    SELECT * FROM mytable
    WHERE id in (select id from another table) 
    ORDER BY prefer DESC
    LIMIT 1 
вернет тока одно значение - а надо со всех ид собрать имена

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (id,COALESCE(prefer, -1)) IN ( SELECT id, MAX(COALESCE(prefer, -1))
                       FROM table
                       GROUP BY id
                     );
```

Comment: Как `IN` обрабатывает `NULL` значения? Считаются ли они равными?

Comment: @PetSerAl Да, верно. Что-то не подумал, Счас поправим... готово. Спасибо за поправку.

Comment: Чтобы не вводить специальное значение, можно было заменить `IN` на `<=> ANY`.

Comment: наверно тут все верно, но вот как добавить к этому еще список идешек по которым искать? SELECT name from table (some magic) and where id in (select id from another_table);